# How much damage carries over, or which attack triggers the end of Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, polymorph

[*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) is said to be a great spell, and I can see why: it can turn a CR 18 monstrosity into a CR 0 Frog, or something along those lines.  My question comes from one specific paragraph in *polymorph*'s text:

> The target assumes the hit points of its new form. When it reverts to its normal form, the creature returns to the number of hit points it had before it transformed. If it reverts as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form.

Say a fighter, level 11, attacks a creature that has been polymorphed into a [Frog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/frog) (AC of 11, 1 HP).  The fighter has 3 attacks thanks to his Extra Attack class feature, so when the fighter uses his action to attack, he attacks the frog three times.

1 hit is guaranteed to exceed the 1 HP of the frog.

Would that attack end the *polymorph* spell, and the remaining 2 attacks be against the original creature's AC and HP? Or, would the *polymorph* end at the end of the Attack action, meaning the fighter got all 3 attacks against the AC 11 Frog?

Comment: Note that that wiki is not an official rules source, and frequently misquotes descriptions in a futile attempt to avoid getting taken down by WotC. I've edited an updated link and a fixed quote into your post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The polymorphed creature would revert after the first attack.

The *[Polymorph](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Polymorph#content)* spell text says that the spell ends when the creature reaches 0 hp.

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies.

When the opponent takes the Attack action, each attack has its own attack and damage roll. So if the first attack drops the polymorphed creature to 0 hp, the spell ends and they revert forms and take any damage left over. Then the opponent continues with their other attack rolls, which would be done against the AC and HP of the creature's normal form.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to D&D 5E, so I am still learning about actions and how they are implemented in regards to other things.